# How does a single-threaded event driven webserver (like node.js) work at the socket level?

Tags: multithreading, node.js, sockets

So I keep hearing from friends how node.js somehow does everything using a single thread. By that, I assume it means that it accepts new socket connections via a looping thread that waits on an "accept" method (like most web servers), and then rather than delegating the socket it receives to a new thread for handling, it somehow gets a single thread to handle all the connections.

Everyone tells me that's not the case though, and that it's actually event driven - such that things only happen on demand (i.e. a request coming in from a client).

However, having worked with sockets on the lowest level, I understand that usually if you want to respond to a request immediately, you need to have a thread sitting and blocking on a read from the socket it's waiting on.

So my question is, how does something like node achieve this? Is there a background thread constantly checking each "event" socket in the background for incoming data successively, and reacting when there is an event (i.e. spawning a new thread to deal with it)?

Is node actually single threaded, or am I misinterpreting the meaning of single threaded?

Comment: The code you write runs in a single thread, although it may receive events from other threads (such as threads sitting on a socket wait).  I don't know the technical details much beyond that, so I'll leave answering to someone more knowledgeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding, it is the **event loop of NodeJS that is single-threaded**.

There are other threads controlled behind the scenes for basically any IO operation - sockets, files, TCP, etc. Those threads are managed by the NodeJS executable and their numbers grow and shrink as needed, and as "system level" calls are made in Node. Currently, my `node` processes is reporting 8 threads in MacOSX Activity Monitor.

So the IO threads and other important system-level things we need not worry about too much *are occuring* behind the scenes. What we do need to worry about is the main event loop, our single thread, because it can only process one event at a time.

**An analogy**

I borrowed this idea from an article I lost the link to, but the main node process, that executes the event loop, is "the King Thread" as passes out directions to Servant Threads (the IO - sockets, files, TCP, etc.). The King Thread only has to handle one event at a time, and Servant Threads line up to let the king thread execute their particular event. Should that Servant Thread require information elsewhere (as in, "a callback"), the King Thread will stop dealing with that Servant Thread and move on to the next Servant Thread in the event queue. The Servant Threads can continue working or gathering information while the King Thread is dealing with all the events of the kingdom.

In this way the King Thread only had to deal with one event at a time, and very quickly because he is an efficient King Thread. Should some Servant Thread talk his ear off, all the other Servant Threads in the event line must wait their turn. **But** any Servant Thread off gathering information for the King Thread (like pulling in a HTTP request or pushing out a DB query) can continue to work *at full speed*, until it has the information for the King Thread, at which time he hops into the queue for the King Thread's processing of its event.

Hope that helps : )